# Pointer to QList - at() vs. [] operator

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qlist

I'm having problem with understanding some of QList behavior.

```
#include <QList>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    QList<double> *myList;

    myList = new QList<double>;
    double myNumber;
    double ABC;

    for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
    {
        myNumber = i;
        myList->append(myNumber);
        ABC = myList[i]; //<----------!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        cout << ABC << endl;
    }

    cout << "Done!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get compilation error **cannot convert ‘QList’ to ‘double’ in assignment** at marked line. It works when I use `ABC = myList.at(i)`, but QT reference seems to say that `at()` and `[] operator` is same thing.
Does anybody know what makes the difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because `operator[]` should be applied to a `QList` *object*, but `myList` is a **pointer** to `QList`.

Try

```
ABC = (*myList)[i];
```

instead. (Also, the correct syntax should be `myList->at(i)` instead of `myList.at(i)`.)

Comment: yes I meant myList->at(i) - mistyping in question, thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

You've probably meant

```
ABC = (*myList)[i];
```

Answer (score 3):

myList is a pointer to QList therefore you should use it as `(*myList)[i]` in the line marked with exclamation marks. Also, you cannot use `ABC = myList.at(i)`, you have to use ABC = `myList->at(i)`